# Outlook VBA macro to search by colour category

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

I want to make a VBA macro to search ALL folders including my online archive by colour category `RED`

Don't have a clue where to start with this!

I have a text search one but this obviously doesn't do colours.

```
Sub SearchMacro()
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
txtSearch = "category:(Business)"
myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders
Set myOlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you tried:

```
txtSearch = "category:=""Red category"""
```

Complete:

```
Sub Red()
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
txtSearch = "category:=""Red category"""
myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders
Set myOlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```