# How to enter a string in the search field?

Tags: vba, search, outlook

I would like to enter a string into the Search Bar in the main window of Outlook.

This is what I mean by Search Bar

[image]

Entering the string would be enough, as a first step.

An example of a string is: category:="Urgent" received:this week

I've done a few attempts with View objects and DASL filters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook VBA macro to search by colour category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791242/outlook-vba-macro-to-search-by-colour-category)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub showMailviaRef()

Dim refCode As String ' define your reference

refCode = Selection ' Referance code selection in your excel sheet

With Outlook.ActiveExplorer

.ClearSearch ' Clear previous search if any
.Search refCode, olSearchScopeAllFolders
.Display 'Shows search results

 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: `refCode = "category:=""Urgent"" received:this week"`. This removes the mention of Excel. Note the extra quotes around "Urgent". `Debug.Print refCode` to see the string in the required format.