# How to search by choosing a category from the category dialog?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

I would like to search for keywords on the Outlook Search bar. The ideal process is that I can use search Tool hotkey to add the attributes (e.g. *Sent To*, *Receiver*, *cc*, etc.).

I intuitively think the attributes or keywords will exist on a specific mail item. It works when I search for *Sent To*, *Receiver*, and *cc*, but it has some problems when I would like to search a specific category by "Category". It will not show the complete Category List. There is a relevant comment here.

[image: There is a relevant comment here]

There is an illustrated picture for reference for the practical operation.

[image: Illustrated picture for reference]

Since I have lots of categories to manage my emails, I wish to choose a Category by Complete Category Dialog, and input it to Outlook Search Bar. Then I can more quickly and precisely find the mails I want.

There is my preliminary thinking for the VBA code. ([Credit to MarcinSzaleniec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791242/outlook-vba-macro-to-search-by-colour-category)):

```vb
Sub SearchByInputFromCategoryDialog
  'Open Category Dialog and choose one category
  StringOfCategory = Choosing Text
 
  txtSearch = "category:="category:(StringOfCategory )"
  myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders
end Sub
```

Then the category text would show onto Search Bar so that I can further keystroke the "enter" and start the searching process.

*Remarks:*

An issue might exist for Category Dialog, since I can't find if there exists the VBA approach to get the text of category by the category dialog.

The most information I found on the Internet [mainly focus on an item or selected item on explorer to add the category by the category dialog](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/3vynfi/outlook_vba_macro_to_open_categories_dialog/), however the approach I would like to use is *get category text by category dialog*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the category from an object that supports categories.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub SearchByInputFromCategoryDialog()

    Dim StringOfCategory As String
    Dim txtSearch As String
    
    Dim obj As Object
        
    'Open Category Dialog and choose one category
    Set obj = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    obj.ShowCategoriesDialog
    StringOfCategory = obj.categories
    Debug.Print StringOfCategory
    
    'txtSearch = "category:=""Red category"""
    'Debug.Print txtSearch
    
    txtSearch = "category:=""" & StringOfCategory & """"
    Debug.Print txtSearch
     
    ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, the function is completely meet my requirement. I appreciate the great help ~